# Locally trying to run migration with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, migrate, laravel-artisan

I 'm tryin to create this table but I get an error from symfony.

php artisan migrate:make create_foobar_table --create --table="foobar_table"

sudo php artisan migrate:make create_foobar_table --create --table="foobar_table"

Error below:
[image]

My composer file is up to date with all dependencies resolved from what I see and I'm connected to my mysql remote db. Any ideas?

Comment: You should not have to run this command with sudo access. What are the permissions of the project directory? does the user running this command have access to read / write ?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x are permissions for project. You're right I didn't have to run in sudo. Nonetheless, I get the same result if I do.

Comment: Is the table effectively created after running the command? Do you see the same error when doing `composer du`?

Comment: No, it does not create the table when i run php artisan migrate. I do see the migration file created though.

Comment: And do you see the same error when doing `composer du`?

Comment: [ErrorException]                                                                                                                            
  file_put_contents(..../vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied) I get that error when I do composer du

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for this command is like this:

```
php artisan migrate:make create_foobar_table --create=foobar_table
```

You don't need the `--table` parameter.